# How to align left and right on same line in mpdf

Tags: php, css-float, mpdf

I try this HTML code

```
<p class="alignleft">Text on the left.</p>
<p class="alignright">Text on the right.</p>
```

and CSS code

```
.alignleft{
    float: left;
}
.alignright{
    float: right;
}
```

include mpdf

```
ob_start();
..HTML..
$pdf = new mPDF('th', 'A4', '0', 'THSaraban','30','20','15');
$stylesheet = file_get_contents('mpdf/style_mpdf.css');
$html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$pdf->SetAutoFont();
$pdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
$pdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet, 1);
$pdf->WriteHTML($html, 2);
$pdf->Output();
```

It worked on HTML but in mpdf doesn't

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$html= "<p align='left'>Text on the left.</p><p align='right'>Text on the right.</p>";
$mpdf->SetColumns(2, 'J');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html, 2);
$pdf->Output();
```

Reference: [here](http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=139).